# Filtering in EF Generic Repository but still returning ObjectSet<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, objectset

I have a generic Repository that returns an ObjectSet from the objectContext.CreateObjectSet method.

Depending on T, I'd like to use something like :

```
var objectSet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
if (typeof(IAbc).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
{
         return objectSet.Where(x => ((IAbc)x).Abc == "hey");
}
```

While still being able to return ObjectSet instead of IQueryable.

Does anyone know of a way of accomplishing this or something similar?

Comment: You are providing a filter so you no longer have an "object set" but rather a "query" (a subset). The ObjectSet class is meant to represent the ENTIRE set.

Comment: Is there any way to hack this in? I'm dealing with legacy code here and it's the difference between touching 500+ places and figuring out how to put a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: How are you acquiring the object context? Can you share that piece of code?

Comment: `var context = (EntityContext) EntityContext;
   var adapter = context as IObjectContextAdapter;
   var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;
   objectContext.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = proxyCreationEnabled;
   var objectSet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();

Comment: What's the original type of EntityContext? I think I may have a solution for you.

Comment: DbContext is the original type - It derives from DBContext, it's IEntityContext

Comment: You are in luck sir. Try this: http://matthidinger.com/archive/2012/01/25/a-smarter-infrastructure-automatically-filtering-an-ef-4-1-dbset/